# How to set default language in MVC RouteConfig?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, routeconfig

I have a `Language` table on my database. There is one primary language. My software on layered architecture. Layers : Domain-Data(Repository)-Business-Presentation And I am using Ninject for DI.

So, I should get primary language while application start and set my url like : `{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}`

How can I do this? Because I couldn't access to my business layer on `RouteConfig.cs` or `Global.asax` Is there a way to do this?

I want to do like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        private ILanguageBusiness _languageBusiness;
        public RouteConfig(ILanguageBusiness languageBusiness)
        {
            _languageBusiness = languageBusiness;
        }
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { language = _languageBusiness.GetPrimaryLanguageCode(), controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the issue you are facing with this code?

Comment: This code cant work. Because RegisterRoutes is static. I need get primary language while application start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. RouteConfig file should be like that to get primary language.

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            var languageBusiness = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILanguageBusiness>();
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { language = languageBusiness.GetPrimaryLanguage().Code, controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```